# htaccess to block all bots/crawlers/spiders except ones I allow

Tags: .htaccess

I'm looking for an aggressive block via htaccess, not robots.txt

I don't want to list every unfriendly bot under the sun, rather block them all and allow only the ones I want.

After some research I've come up with this which should block everything I listed including user agents that are not identifying themselves and are just blank or identified as \

Would this work?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (bot|robot|crawl|krawler|spider|libwww-perl.*|-?|\ ) [NC] #blocked
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(googlebot|bingbot|msnbot|yahoo) [NC] #allowed
RewriteRule - [F]
```

Comment: What crawlers are you trying to stop? Why?

Comment: To add a layer of protection to the site and servers resources. After analyzing raw access logs of several of my sites I saw all kinds of bots scanning and probing the site, accessing folders and files that don't exist which is obviously looking for vulnerabilities and exploits. I don't want any of them having access except ones I specifically allow.

Comment: You have to decide whether to use a deny-by-default (whitelist), or allow-by-default (blacklist) methodology for this, both of which have pain points. Allowing all traffic except the ones you blacklist will still allow other, lesser-known bots through, and you'll have to keep tweaking that list to block them. On the other hand, blocking all traffic except the ones you whitelist will have the same problem of constant whitelist tweaks to allow legitimate traffic. It may be sufficient in some cases to cover only the major browsers, but you risk blocking some of the more niche ones this way.